# TypeScript mapped type for proxy

Tags: typescript, proxy-pattern, mapped-types

I want to achieve a conceptually simple thing: transform a map of functions that return `any` (or, for the sake of the example, `number`) to a map of functions that return `void`, while conserving the other type information.

Expressed in code, I would like to do something like this:

```
type Source = {
    [fn: string]: (...args: any[]) => number
}

type Output = {
    [fn: string]: (...args: any[]) => void
}

function proxy(source: Source): Output {
    // Do something with the source...
    return source
}

const result = proxy({
    answerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything: (question?: string): number => 42
})

// Should work, and the method should be suggested as part of the auto-completion.
result.answerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything()

// The compiler should complain.
result.answerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything(false)
```

Comment: Why would the compiler complain in your second call?

Comment: Because the function expects a string, but in the second call I'm providing a boolean.

Comment: Did you read the article on advanced types, specifically the section about "mapped types" here? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: I did, but still I fail to see how to apply the knowledge there to the case in hand.